# Program crashes while trying to print strings from allocated memory

Tags: c, malloc

I was testing `malloc` to see if the allocated memory keeps its data if the program exits without `free()`.I save the addresses to file,and in another program use these addresses to test,but it's crashing.why does that happen ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    if(fopen_s(&file,"file.txt","w"))
        exit(-1);
    char *p1 = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    char *p2 = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    strcpy(p1,"A");
    strcpy(p2,"B");

    fprintf(file,"%x\n",p1);
    fprintf(file,"%x\n",p2);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
*/
int main(void)
{
    //these two addresses are from the saved file
    char *p1 = (char*)0x341440;
    char *p2 = (char*)0x341468;

    printf("%s\n",p1);
    printf("%s\n",p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not how memory works. Addresses only make sense *within* one program.

Comment: Memory is not persisted across program invocation. Also, there's no guarantee that two invocations of the same program will allocate to the exact same memory addresses.

Comment: @keithmo: There is indeed even less of any such guarantee if the program does not even call `malloc()`

Comment: ..because the allocated memory does not keep its data if the program exits without free().  Only trivial systems would allow anything like what you are attempting.

Answer (score 1):

It crashes because malloc doesn't save it's contents between runs and so in your second run you are printing from uninitialized pointers.

What did you expect "failure of the premise" to look like? A working print but with different values?